# Particular bash completion files not working when in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions but work fine in /etc/bash_completion.d

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a git repository where I keep some statically-linked binaries along with related man files and bash completion files, which are all 'installed' using [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to make the symlinks.

I have previously put the symlinks for the bash completion files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` with no issues, but recently I have started putting them in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` instead, as I thought it was a more correct location for them, seeing as the binaries were going in `/usr/local/bin` and the man files in `/usr/local/share/man`.

Everything works as before apart from four specific bash completion files, which are no longer working when placed in this new location. These are:

- [git-identity.bash-completion](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/madx/git-identity/master/git-identity.bash-completion)
- [tmux.completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bash-it/bash-it/master/completion/available/tmux.completion.bash)

And these two for fzf:

- [completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/fzf/master/shell/completion.bash)
- [key-bindings.bash](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/raw/master/shell/key-bindings.bash)

I have 20 other bash completion files that work fine. What is it about these specific bash completion files that make them work while in `/etc/bash_completion.d` with no issues but not in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`?

**EDIT:**
They also don't work in `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions` either.

---

#### Additional information:

The files are sourced by the standard Debian/Ubuntu `.bashrc` lines:

```
# Enable programmable completion features
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

In both locations it is not the contents on directories are that being sourced, but these two files:

[/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion](http://sprunge.us/t0AJHb)

[/etc/bash_completion](http://sprunge.us/4QfuCa)

The second file simply points to the first file if NOT `shopt -oq posix`. On my setup:

```
$ if ! shopt -oq posix; then echo "not posix"; fi
not posix
```

I think the answer must be in [/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion](http://sprunge.us/t0AJHb).

---

#### More:

I tried replacing `bash_completion` with the latest version but that doesn't work either.

https://github.com/scop/bash-completion

#### Also..

These files do not work when placed in `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions` either.

Comment: Are you sourcing them?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, as I mentioned, 29 other completion files in the same location work fine. There is something about these four specific files that are causing them to not work when in the new location.

Comment: What does `type _git_identity` say for example?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `bash: type: _git_identity: not found`

Comment: What if you source git-identity.bash-completion manually?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, if I source the file in the stow-installed location it works

Comment: So what exact command did you use?

Comment: `$ source git-identity.bash-completion`

Comment: The script can return at any place, for example
git-identity.bash-completion returns on `[ -n "$__git_whitespacelist"
] || return;` so let's make a test - add something before this line,
for example `touch /tmp/GIT-COMPLETION-SOURCED`, start a new bash
session and check if file exists. Also, post output of `ls -Alh
git-identity.bash-completion`.

Comment: The test shows that the file is not being sourced at all. `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 Sep 18 02:10 git-identity.bash-completion -> ../../../../home/jason/.dotfiles/bin/completions/git-identity.bash-completion`

Comment: (the file doesn't work in those location as a file and not a symlink either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` are always sourced immediately by `bash_completion` for
backwards compatibility. The `completions` directories, on the other hand, lazily source the scripts
inside, that is, a particular completion file isn't sourced until completion is requested for that
command. The file to source is determined by its name, thus it must have the same name as the
command you're trying to get completions for. So, for example, `tmux.completion.bash` should be
symlinked as `completions/tmux` and not `completions/tmux.completion.bash`.

Finally, as you're putting everything else under `/usr/local`, note that you can put the completion
scripts there as well: `/usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I should have noticed that these files are not named like all the others that do work. I'll add they also work with a `.bash` or `.sh` suffix. This presents a problem with the `fzf` files which don't work when concatenated to `fzf.bash`, but I can always specifically source those files in the same location from `.bashrc`.

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be true for me. My system has `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`, but I have no git completion (it just attempts to complete filenames in all scenarios). If I run `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`, I then have "smart" completion in that terminal. I'm fine with sourcing it in my `.bashrc`, but your answer suggests I shouldn't have to. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do completions work for other commmands? If not, make sure you're sourcing `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`. Other than that you can try starting bash with `bash -x` and completing as usual (type `git ` followed by Tab), which should output a bunch of executed commands. When git completion is working properly you should see `__load_completion git` execute, which searches for the `completions/git` script and sources it.